# How do I write a MongoDB $exists query in Perl?

Tags: mongodb, perl

db.getCollection('Subscriber').find({$and:[{"registerFrom":{$exists:false}},{"googleRegistrationId":{$exists:true}},{"isGuest":"false"}]})

how to write the above query in Perl please help this.I am getting different results on this when execute on perl

i have written like this in perl

my $Subscriber2 = $Subscriber->find({'$and' =>[{dateOfJoining => {'$gt' =>  $date}},{registerFrom => { '$exists' => 'false'}},{googleRegistrationId => {'$exists' => 'true'}},{isGuest => 'false'}]})->fields({ _id => 1,streamzCampaigns => 1});

I am not getting the same results as when executing in perl.How to use $exits of mongoDB in Perl.Please help on this one.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You might want to take the [tour] and read about how to create a [mcve]. Please format the code to make it readable.

Comment: That's not really an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), since I can't actually run it, but I'll still try to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two suspicious bits I see are that you've quoted "true" and "false" -- which make those strings, not boolean values -- and I wonder what you're using for `$date`, since you don't have that in your shell example.

Here is what you wrote, formatted nicely:

```
my $Subscriber2 = $Subscriber->find(
    {
        '$and' => [
            { dateOfJoining        => { '$gt'     => $date } },
            { registerFrom         => { '$exists' => 'false' } },
            { googleRegistrationId => { '$exists' => 'true' } },
            { isGuest              => 'false' }
        ]
    }
)->fields( { _id => 1, streamzCampaigns => 1 } );
```

For the booleans, you should use the [boolean.pm](https://p3rl.org/boolean) module:

```
use boolean;

my $Subscriber2 = $Subscriber->find(
    {
        '$and' => [
            { dateOfJoining        => { '$gt'     => $date } },
            { registerFrom         => { '$exists' => false } },
            { googleRegistrationId => { '$exists' => true } },
            { isGuest              => false }
        ]
    }
)->fields( { _id => 1, streamzCampaigns => 1 } );
```

Comment: after using boolean and removing single coat i am getting correct answer thanks